# Batch script for mapping drives on a remote PC - User prompt for username variable

Tags: shell, windows-scripting

We have a share drive that contains a network share for each individual under the simple scheme of first initial last name. (JSmith, APeterson, etc.)

I am trying to create a universal batch script that can map to their unique drive by prompting them for their username. I've tested the batch script successfully to \Share\Users\, but I am consistently getting a System error 53, network path was not found.

This tells me I'm doing something dumb and incorrect with declaring the variable portion of mapping. Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong or if there is a better way to do this? We're using Palo Alto's GlobalProtect as a VPN client, but to my knowledge they don't have any built-in method to map network drives upon proper authentication.

Code is as follows:

set /p %user%="Enter username: "

@net use H: \Share\Users\%user% /persistent:yes
:exit
@pause

Thank you in advance for help/input!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I thought I had done enough research but this ended up being a dumb oversight...

I was duplicating the %'s. I should not have included the %% in the variable. Removing the percent signs worked successfully.

I'll leave this here for anyone else who may have the same oversight or this command may help.

Here it is in the correct form:

set /p user="Enter Username: "

@net use H: \Share\Users\%user% /persistent:yes
:exit
@pause